# EAR classloader problem in WebLogic: Keycloak-Admin-Client TokenService interface not found

Tags: java, keycloak, weblogic, java-ee-7

I have an (existing) **EAR** application running on **WebLogic 12.2.1 (Java EE 7)** where I am working on including a **Keycloak Admin Client** (for user management on a **Red Hat SSO 7.6** installation).
The simplified structure is this:

```
EAR
- /lib
  - keycloak-admin-client-18.0.9.redhat-00001.jar
- EJBModule
  - EJB classes
- WebAppModule (WAR)
  - JAX-RS resources, calling EJBs
```

The EJB classes and webapps work fine (already existing, no changes there yet).
I created a new EJB for the user management ("KeycloakUserManagementService"), containing a builder for a `Keycloak` instance:

```
Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder().serverUrl(url)
    .realm(realmName)
    .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
    .clientId(clientId)
    .clientSecret(clientSecret)
    .build();
```

This builder fails with the following exception:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenService is not visible from class loader`

I verified that the source jar is the correct jar "keycloak-admin-client-18.0.9.redhat-00001.jar" inside the EAR, by adding this in the new EJB class:

```
URL pathToJar = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenService").getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

Usually, when classloader issues happen (necessary for Guava, Jackson etc) it's a matter of adding the packages to `weblogic.xml` and `weblogic-application.xml` like this, but that did not work for the Keycloak classes:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>org.keycloak.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

Already tried:

1. Running the same builder in the WebAppModule works fine. (this is not a solution due to how the total application is setup over modules with various responsibilities)
2. Verifying that there are no duplicate class definitions on the classpath. As far as I can see this is not the case.

***Question:***

Any ideas what is going wrong and how I can fix it?
As far as I can see the correct class from the correct .jar is loaded.